# How to convert an array of string into a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object

Each user's information is separated by a comma, or a space, but some pieces of information can be blank. I'm looking for a solution to take the user information and create an object (key-value mapping). Here's my approach, but I can't get multiple objects.

```js
function Person(name, email, age, occupation) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.age = age;
  this.occupation = occupation;
}

let string = "Norbert,norbert@test.com,51,Coder Noemi,,,Teacher Rachel,rachel@test.com,,"
let stringArr = string.split(/[\s,]+/)

const personObj = new Person(...stringArr)

console.log(personObj)
```

Comment: First split on spaces. Then split each of those strings on commas. If there are spaces in either name or occupation this won't work, but the format is ambiguous in that case anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a CSV parser

Answer (score 1):

When splitting the string, you need to keep the empty strings between the commas, but you are splitting sequences of commas as one divider - `[\s,]+`.

Split the string by a single `,` or a sequence of spaces - `/,|\s+/`. Then create an array of `Person` using `Array.from()`, dividing the original length by 4, and taking 4 properties by slicing the original array:

```js
function Person(name, email, age, occupation) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.age = age;
  this.occupation = occupation;
}

const string = "Norbert,norbert@test.com,51,Coder Noemi,,,Teacher Rachel,rachel@test.com,,"
const stringArr = string.split(/,|\s+/)

const personArr = Array.from({ length: stringArr.length / 4 }, (_,i) => 
  new Person(...stringArr.slice(i * 4, i * 4 + 4))
)

console.log(personArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming space is a line separator, and comma is a field separator, split:

```js
function Person(name, email, age, occupation) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.age = age;
  this.occupation = occupation;
}

let string = "Norbert,norbert@test.com,51,Coder Noemi,,,Teacher Rachel,rachel@test.com,,";

const persons = string.split(' ').map(r => new Person(...r.split(',')));

console.log(persons)
```